# LibGDX: Its there any way to calculate the speed of a repeated scrolling background?

Tags: libgdx

I'm trying to calculate the scrolling speed of an background, I'm doing something like this on the background class:

```
private Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("backgound.png"));
private Sprite sprite;

private float scrollTimer = 0.0f;
private static float scrollFactor = 0.2f;


public Background() {
    texture.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat);
    int width = texture.getWidth();
    int height = texture.getHeight();
    sprite = new Sprite(texture, 0, 0, width, height);
    sprite.setSize(1280, 320);

}

@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    updateScrollFactor();
    scrollTimer += delta * scrollFactor;

    if (scrollTimer > 1.0f) {
        scrollTimer = 0.0f;
    }

    sprite.setU(scrollTimer);
    sprite.setU2(scrollTimer + 2);
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha) {
    sprite.draw(batch, alpha);
}

private void updateScrollFactor() {
    //Increase scroll factor when the game score being higher.
}

public static float getScrollFactor() {
    return scrollFactor;
}
```

And in another class I'm trying to calculate the speed of this background above because I need the same speed to apply in the entity of mentioned class, that is described below:

```
private Texture texture;
private Sprite sprite;

public Item(String textureName) {
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(textureName));
    int width = texture.getWidth();
    int height = texture.getHeight();
    sprite = new Sprite(texture, 0, 0, width, height);
    sprite.setSize(30f, 50f);
    //Sets initial position, the entity will be scrolled from the screen width to zero  
    sprite.setPosition(Gdx.app.getWidth() - 10, 10);
}

@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    scrollTimer = delta * Background.getScrollFactor();

    if (scrollTimer > 1.0f) {
        scrollTimer = 0.0f;
    }

    float x = sprite.getX();
    if (x + sprite.getWidth() > 0) {
        sprite.setX(x - Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * scrollTimer);
    } else {
        //sets to initial position when the entity vanish thru the window left side.
        sprite.setX(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 10);
    }
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha) {
    sprite.draw(batch, alpha);
}
```

}

The case is the entity don't run sync with background but i need this separated from the background because it is a clickable entity.

Thoughts?

Comment: I think you're on the right track. Why don't you have a velocity or speed parameter for background? I'm not sure what's going on with your "scrollTimer" or how it's supposed to work. Once you have a velocity parameter you can share that just like you're sharing scrollFactor and it should work.

Comment: Since you are controlling the scrolling background, you should know exactly what its speed is, because you made it:P  I would suggest using the game's EllapsedGameTime Property multiplied by a integer of your choosing beforehand.  That was if you are looking to get the scroll speed, you will have a definitive idea of what the speed is.
Ex: 
    public Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(300, 0);
    MoveToLoc -= (velocity * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds);